# Multiple PHP dynamic variables displaying other dynamic variable values

Tags: php, variables, dynamic

I am generating dynamic variables like so:

```
    $testPMA = '';
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM site_pma") or die(mysql_error());  
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        ${$testPMA.$row['id']} = $row['value'];
      } 
    $testLocation = '';
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM site_location") or die(mysql_error());  
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        ${$testLocation.$row['id']} = $row['value'];
      }
```

then I try displaying them like so:

```
    if(isset(${$testPMA.$row_bom_lines['pma']})) echo ${$testPMA.$row_bom_lines['pma']};
```

The first one returns correctly.  The next column and any after always take their id number for the dynamic variable, but only generate PMA.  They never update to show Location or any other one I have created.  I even tried mysql_free_result($result); after each one.  How do I get the dynamic variable to display each of their own vs displaying the same table information for each column, just with an updated id number?

Comment: You really really really should consider ditching this code entirely. variable variables are BAD. They're hard to maintain, and harder yet to debug (as you're now realizing). Why do they have to be variables at all? Why not use an array with your `$row['id']` as the array key?

Comment: Thank you!  I did that and everything is working just the way I want.